# How to add "--production" option in meteor-up configuration (mupx)?

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I've successfully deployed a meteor app, but I can't find out how to use the `--production` option when configuring [Meteor-Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) (mupx)

I'd like to add this option to have all the css and js files compiled in the client side.

I also need to specify `--release <release-name>`, but hopefully both options will be possible in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set your environment variable in mup.json file.

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "hostname",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "env": {
        DEV_ENV="development",
        DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=urlHere
        MONGO_URL=mongo uri here
      }
    }

  ...
}
```